# King Solomon's mines

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

I am playing in an RPG and the GM set a puzzle for us that I have no clue about. I am bringing it here in the hope that you can shed light on it. I don't know the answer at this stage. And for those worried about ethics I will be telling the GM how I came up with the answer if somebody here answers it for me. :)

So the situation is we are in King Solomon's mines. We have found a room that seems to be the entrance to the treasure room. Above the door are the words:

“Here stands the entrance to the kings treasure room. Only with wisdom may one enter. What do you seek?”

Inside on the floor are tiles with letters on (the colouration in it was not in the original - that is just me marking the vowels to try to make some sense of it). There is no further indication of what to do. My assumption (that may be wrong) is that there is a path across the letters spelling out a word (or phrase) with the writing above the door being the clue to it.

[image]

P.S. I wasn't sure what to tag it. If anybody wants to suggest better tags of course feel free. And of course suggestions on how to improve the question welcome.

Comment: You probably want the enigmatic-puzzle tag since it is not clear what to do...

Comment: Have you attempted a wisdom check? In case that might reveal more about the puzzle that may or may not be required to solve it.

Comment: You can trace the word "SOLDERS" starting from the middle S in the top row. Clearly you should... erm... solder the door. A DnD breadboarding puzzle... :p

Comment: Not D&D so no wisdom check. I don't *think* there are any more clues to be had by passing any other skill checks though from the context.

Comment: Pitons in the wall *is always an option*.

Comment: I was gonna say you could spell Jehovah with one letter from each row, but there's no H in the last row.

Comment: The book od proverbs is attributed to Solomon,  who valued virtue above gemstones,  upon entering the treasure room you may be dissapointed. https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+31%3A10-31&version=KJV

Comment: Maybe it's a distraction.  Are you *sure* the door to the treasure room is locked?

Comment: @Chris Name the game for us. Maybe that might help

Comment: @RahulSrinath: Its the rippers setting of savage worlds. Pulp/horror victorian stuff.

Comment: You can also trace 'VOLTRON' across floor without jumping.. perhaps the wise old king was a fan?

Comment: @jpmc26 Jehovah can be spelled out, if one walks on H twice. This could be the first word of the message.

Comment: If you want more puzzles like this: Microsoft has an app for you: http://www.wordament.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found "Soloman" going from Entrance to Exit.
>
>
>
>  I also found "Move", "Past"
>
> and maybe a word that ends in "orted"
>
>  [image]

Comment: maybe it's "aborted"? i don't know

Comment: I think "SOLOMON" is supposed to be the solution.

Comment: @Deusovi It asks "What do you seek?", not "Who do you seek?".  I found SAMOSAS.

Comment: SOLOMON was indeed the solution. My assumption that it required adjacent letters was wrong. Good job! :)

Answer (score 3):

> I see the words "Move past..."  Given that this is about a RPG, that
>  information  could be useful if the room is booby trapped. (For the
>  record, this was the first answer to the question.)
>
>
>  [image]

Other possibilities:

> "Six moves":
>  
>  [image]
>
>  "Save it" which could also be "Save me" using the **m** right below
>  the **e** and backtracking:
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  "I love diners":
>
>  [image]

Comment: There's another "move(s)" at the top of the board.

Comment: You could do "SOLD TAN" with contiguous letters. lol. TRAP is near PAST, too.

Comment: The "Six Moves" is something I wish I would've seen, it seems like that must be part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see the word "VOLE TRAP" written there, but that's probably just noise,
have your party's trap specialist inspect as much of the floor as possible without disturbing any of it that may reduce your options to a smaller set.

Answer (score 1):

'SOLOMON'.

There is an 'S' on the first line, an 'O' on the second, 'L' on the third, etc.

Or it could be 'VICTORY', with the same. [Credit to @MOehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36885/king-solomons-mines/36980?noredirect=1#comment109776_36980)

Comment: "Victory" works, too, and might be a better answer to "What do you seek?"

Comment: Mmmm.... Samosas.   That's so much better than victory.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the answer is 'Vole Trap"?
[image]